# i'm trying to make a 2 players racing game with pygame and event.key don't work

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to make a 2-player racing game, and when I try to add the `event.key == pygame.K_LEFT` it says `AttributeError: 'Event' object has no attribute 'key'`.

I have tried many things as adding `()`, but nothing fixed it and I have no clue about it.

Code:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

display_width = 1280
display_height = 720

black = (0, 0, 0)
white = (255, 255, 255)
red = (255, 0, 0)
green = (0, 255, 0)
blue = (0, 0, 255)

gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width, display_height))
pygame.display.set_caption('U-race multiplayer')
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

car1 = pygame.image.load('car1.png')

def carone(xone, yone):
    gameDisplay.blit(car1,(xone, yone))

xone = (display_width * 0.48)
yone = (display_height * 0.8)

xone_change = 0


crashed = False

while not crashed:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            crashed = True

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
               xone_change = -5
        elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            xone_change = 5

        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                xone_change = 0
```

error message:

```
 RESTART: C:\Users\Osamas\Desktop\U-racing multiplayer\U-racing multiplayer.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Osamas\Desktop\U-racing multiplayer\U-racing multiplayer.py", line 44, in <module>
    elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
AttributeError: 'Event' object has no attribute 'key'
```

Comment: `elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:` is your issue.... You want `elif event.type == pygame.keydown:` and add  if event.key == pygame.k_right` or you want the answer down below..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
    if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
        xone_change = -5
    elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT: #indented to be part of the keydown events
        xone_change = 5
```

You want this. Your indentation was wrong.

You had `elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:` checking with your event.type which doesn't make sense if you think about it.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you're getting an error is because different events have different attributes. You can check which event has which attributes at the official [pygame docs](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html).

Let's take an example between two types of events:

1. QUIT event types has no attributes.
2. KEYDOWN event types has attributes *unicode*, *key* and *mod*.

This means that we cannot check for the *key* attribute in an event until we've made sure that the event is of type `KEYDOWN` (or `KEYUP`).

In your code you have:

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
           xone_change = -5
    elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
        xone_change = 5
```

If the event type isn't `KEYDOWN` then you're checking with the event's *key* attribute, which will raise an attribute error if the event is of type `QUIT`, `MOUSEBUTTONDOWN` or any other event that isn't `KEYDOWN` or `KEYUP`.

To correct this you'll do as MooingRawr answered and make sure that you've indented the two last lines inside the first if-statement. Just thought I'd give an answer to why it's wrong.